# How to use Complex numbers in Class/Object C++

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

Im strugling to implement complex numbers into my code. When I compile it gives me random numbers. It should use imaginary number i = sqrt(-1). It should output realPart + imaginaryPart * i.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
using namespace std;

class Complex
{
private:
    double i;
    complex<double> imaginarypart = i*sqrt(1);
    double realpart;
public:
    void seti(double a1) {
        i = a1;
    }
    void setrealpart(double a2) {
        realpart = a2;
    }
    void printwhole() {
        cout << realpart + imaginarypart;
    }
};

int main()
{
    double a, b;
    cout << "Enter your realpart" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter your imaginarypart " << endl;
    cin >> b;

    Complex num1;
    num1.seti(b);
    num1.setrealpart(a);
    cout << endl;
    num1.printwhole();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a complex object to represent the imaginary part?

Comment: `imaginarypart` is initialized using an uninitialized value of `i`, which is undefined behavior. That's probably where your "random numbers" are coming from.

Comment: I wonder about `cout << realpart + imaginarypart;`. Showing the sum of the two parts seems not so helpful. I'd have expected something like `realpart << '+' << imaginarypart << 'i';`. I.e. showing both parts in one of the widely used representations. And maybe that actually is what you mean by "It should output realPart + imaginaryPart * i.".

Comment: It's also interesting that in initializing `imaginarypart`, you multiply `i` by `sqrt(1)`. Of course the square root of 1 is 1, so the multiplication effectively does nothing. Perhaps you intended to multiply by `sqrt(-1)`, but that has no real solutions so it results in `nan`. I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @FredLarson I suspect that Richardo expected that since he included `<complex>` but not `<cmath>`, that the definition of `std::sqrt` in `<complex>` would be used, which presumably would handle complex numbers correctly. (In my testing, though, this does not appear to be the case. If a number of type `std::complex<double>` is set to `std::sqrt(-1)`, it becomes `(nan,0)`. One has to use `std::sqrt(std::complex<double>(-1,0))` to get a mathematically reasonable result.)

Comment: You probably also want `using namespace std::complex_literals;` so you can use the suffix `i` as in `0 + 2i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that an the type double cannot store imaginary values.
Yet you try to do so, e.g. with `sqrt(1);` (though you probably meant -1).
The `complex<double>` is indeed able to store imaginary values, but on the one hand it won't work by assigning the product of the non-initialised `i` with 1 and on the other hand you seem to try to implement complex numbers yourself. Using the provided complex standard type somewhat defeats that. If you use it, then you just need to learn outputting it in the format you want, instead of doing all the implementation work.

Lets assume that you are more interested in getting it done yourself first.
What you need to do is to always represent complex numbers as two numbers.
I hence propose to change your code likes this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complex
{
private:
    /* double i; Won't work, it cannot store imaginary values. */
    double imaginarypart;
    double realpart;
public:
    void setimaginarypart(double a1) {
        imaginarypart = a1;
    }
    void setrealpart(double a2) {
        realpart = a2;
    }
    void printwhole() {
        cout << realpart << '+' <<  imaginarypart << 'i'; // To get the output you want.
    }
};

int main()
{
    double a, b;
    cout << "Enter your realpart" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter your imaginarypart " << endl;
    cin >> b;

    Complex num1;
    num1.setimaginarypart(b);
    num1.setrealpart(a);
    cout << endl;
    num1.printwhole();
}
```

Alternatively use existing solutions (e.g. std::complex), instead of trying to program one yourself. Outputting them in the shape you want (r+i*I) does not require to implement the whole thing yourself.
Have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex to learn about what it offers.

Comment: "an existing standard type cannot store imaginary values". Of course it can, the standard type `std::complex<double>` can do that.

Comment: @MSalters I think and hope that I incorporated your helpful input.

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out, complex numbers have a real and an imaginary part. And in `std::complex<double>`, those two parts are combined.

But in your class `Complex`, you have `Complex::i`, `Complex::realpart`, `Complex::imaginarypart::real()` and `Complex::imaginarypart::imag()`. That's 4 parts!

Furthermore, `complex<double> imaginarypart = i*sqrt(1);` means that `Complex::imaginarypart` is set to  `i*sqrt(1)` when a `Complex` object is created. But at that time, `i` is still uninitialized! So that won't work either. This is why you get random numbers (or a crash, depending on your luck).

The simple solution is to drop your whole class `Complex`. `std::complex<double>` already has functions to set the real and imaginary parts, namely `std::complex<double>::real(double)` and `std::complex<double>::imag(double)`

(Note: `real` and `imag` are setters if you pass a value, getters if you don't).